# Can anyone tell me how Shopify Api Works?

Tags: shopify

Can anyone tell me how Shopify API works. I'm finding this in google but cant get proper solution so can anyone give me a proper solution for that.

Comment: What do you mean by this ? Do you mean how to _use_ the API ? If so, there's the official docs: https://docs.shopify.com/api

Comment: basically I found this before but cant understand how it works and I also want to know how to build a shopify app. it may be private app or public app but how can I make it. I want to make an app by php

Comment: There are some good resources here: http://gavinballard.com/building-shopify-apps-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify API, you will have to authenticate through shopify api key and secret. And, API endpoint should be the store. Suppose, the store URL is "your-store.myshopify.com" and for product list, you need to call a get request to this "/admin/products.json". Then, the API endpoint will be "https://your-store.myshopify.com/admin/products.json".

So, at the very beginning of API call, you will required to get shop URL and then all the request will be required to call to that URL.